# How to increase numbers in mysql column

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating a bank simulation game and have the cron job working to run my php script every 30 minutes for each "game day".

I have a column, "account_balance" on "player_accounts" table and I would like for that value to increase by x% when each game day is processed.

Basically need to take the current balance and multiply by 1.015 for example so the end result is the principle plus added interest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Multiplication](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/arithmetic-functions.html) is a term:

```
UPDATE player_accounts SET account_balance = account_balance * 1.015
```

Answer (score 2):

```
update account_balance set Amount=(Amount + Amount*(percent/100))
```

here is your answer

Comment: Thanks alot!  I figured it had to be something very simple.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to update the column's value by the percentage you want; for example:

```
update table_name
set col_a=col_a+(col_a*0.10)
```

That's it. It will add 10% to col_a  in the table.

if you want to target specific rows, you can simply add a where condition:

```
update table_name
set col_a=col_a+(col_a*0.10)
where col_x=some_condition
```